# Date time format

Tags: php, date, time, format

i want to set a variable to a particular date like this in php..how to write this function in php? js`myStartDate = new Date('April 1, '+curYear+' 1:59:59');`

Comment: http://php.net/date will give you all the pointers necessary

Comment: click the "Tick" near the answer(s) most helpful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean

```
<?php

$today = date("D M j Y  g:i:s e O");

echo $today;

// Thu Oct 14 2010 10:56:17 Europe/London +0100
```

or why not just

`date('r');`

Comment: thanks. i want to extract year from $today,something like this  $year=date($today); is this correct?

Comment: i want to set a variable to a particular date like this in php..js: myStartDate = new Date('April 1, '+curYear+' 1:59:59');how to write this function in php?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [date](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) in the php manual, you're almost on the right way (just replace the `R` with `eO` ;) ).

it looks like you want the date to be in RFC2822-format, in this case you could also simply use `date("r")`.

Comment: Nearly there, except for the written out Time zone identifier. That seems to be `date("r e");`

Answer (score 0):

Why is this voted down? Its simple but still...

use `date("D M j Y  g:i:s \G\M\TO");` (larg o at the end)

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the php.net site - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php right at the bottom

```
<?php

function zonedate($layout, $countryzone)
{
    if ( $countryzone >> 0 )
    {
        $zone = 3600 * $countryzone;
    }
    else
    {
        $zone = 0;
    }

    $date = gmdate($layout, time() + $zone);
    return $date;
}

$layout = "D M j Y g:i:s e O";
$countryzone = 5.5;

echo zonedate($layout, $countryzone);

?>
```

Try something like this?

Comment: hehe @oezi Beat me to it! Nice one :)